# In Ruby, what's the easiest way to "chomp" at the start of a string instead of the end?

Tags: ruby, string

In Ruby, sometimes I need to remove the new line character at the beginning of a string. Currently what I did is like the following. I want to know the best way to do this. Thanks.

```
s = "\naaaa\nbbbb"
s.sub!(/^\n?/, "")
```

Comment: Do you want to leave trailing newlines in place (at end of line)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`lstrip` seems to be what you want (assuming trailing white space should be kept):

```
>> s = "\naaaa\nbbbb" #=> "\naaaa\nbbbb"
>> s.lstrip #=> "aaaa\nbbbb"
```

From the docs:

> Returns a copy of str with leading whitespace removed. See also
>   String#rstrip and String#strip.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-lstrip

Answer (score 13):

`strip` will remove all trailing whitespace

```
s = "\naaaa\nbbbb"
s.strip!
```

Little hack to chomp leading whitespace:

```
str = "\nmy string"
chomped_str = str.reverse.chomp.reverse
```

Comment: Just to clarify, `String#strip` and `String#strip!` remove both *leading* and *trailing* whitespace. That's why it works in this case.

Comment: yeap `strip will remove all trailing whitespaces` :) But I don't know if he need to remove ONLY leading whitespace or all of them. Anyway there is no `chomp` for leading whitespace

Comment: @fl00r But there is `lstrip` to only strip leading white space :-) I posted an answer.

Answer (score 11):

To be perfectly accurate `chomp` not only can delete whitespace, from the end of a string, but can also delete arbitrary characters.

If the latter functionality is sought, one can use:

```
'\naaaa\nbbbb'.delete_prefix( "\n" )
```

As opposed to `strip` this works for arbitrary characters exactly like `chomp`.

Answer (score 9):

So, just for a bit of clarification, there are three ways that you can go about this: `sub`, `reverse.chomp.reverse` and `lstrip`.

I'd recommend against `sub` because it's a bit less readable, but also because of how it works: by creating a new string that inherits from your old string. Plus you need a regular expression for something that's fairly simple.

So then you're down to `reverse.chomp.reverse` and `lstrip`. Most likely, you want `lstrip` because it's a bit faster, but keep in mind that the `strip` operations are *not* the same as the `chomp` operations. `strip` will remove *all* leading newlines *and* whitespace:

```
"\n  aaa\nbbb".reverse.chomp.reverse  # => "  aaa\nbbb"
"\n  aaa\nbbb".lstrip                 # => "aaa\nbbb"
```

If you want to make sure you only remove one character and that it's definitely a newline, use the `reverse.chomp.reverse` solution. If you consider all leading newlines and whitespace garbage, go with `lstrip`.

The one case I can think of for using regular expressions would be if you have an unknown number of `\r`s and `\n`s at the beginning and want to trim them all but avoid touching any whitespace. You could use a loop and the more String methods for trimming but it would just be uglier. The performance implications don't really matter that much.

Comment: I'd say if he only wants to remove one character that's a newline, his current solution with `sub!` (the in-place version) is a lot better than `reverse.chomp.reverse`.

Answer (score 4):

```
s.sub(/^[\n\r]*/, '')
```

This removes leading newlines (carriage returns and line feeds, as in [chomp](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-chomp)), not any whitespace.

Comment: `\A` for "beginning of string" would perhaps be more proper than `^` for "beginning of line". But the above expression should still work as requested since `sub` together with the asterisk ensures it matches the very first line only.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it's the best way but you could try:

```
s.reverse.chomp.reverse
```

if you want to leave the trailing newline (if it exists).

Comment: Note: if you pass an argument to `chomp`, you're going to want to reverse that too: `s.reverse.chomp(x.reverse).reverse`

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you: `s.strip`.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this for whitespace or non-whitespace characters is like this:

```
s = "\naaaa\nbbbb"
s.slice!("\n") # returns "\n" but s also has the first newline removed.
puts s # shows s has the first newline removed
```