# Multiple Ruby chomp! statements

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a simple method to detect and strip tags from text strings. Given this input string:

```
{{foobar}}
```

The function has to return

```
foobar
```

I thought I could just chain multiple `chomp!` methods, like so:

```
"{{foobar}}".chomp!("{{").chomp!("}}")
```

but this won't work, because the first `chomp!` returns a `NilClass`. I can do it with regular `chomp` statements, but I'm really looking for a one-line solution.

The [String class documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp-21) says that `chomp!` returns a `Str` if modifications have been made - therefore, the second `chomp!` should work. It doesn't, however. I'm at a loss at what's happening here.

For the purposes of this question, you can assume that the input string is always a tag which begins and ends with double curly braces.

Comment: why not `str[2..-3]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely chain multiple `chomp` statements (the non-bang version), still having a one-line solution as you wanted:

```
 "{{foobar}}".chomp("{{").chomp("}}")
```

However, it will not work as expected because both `chomp!` and `chomp` removes the separator only from the end of the string, not from the beginning.

You can use [`sub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-sub)

```
"{{foobar}}".sub(/{{(.+)}}/, '\1')
# => "foobar"

"alfa {{foobar}} beta".sub(/{{(.+)}}/, '\1')
# => "alfa foobar beta"

# more restrictive
"{{foobar}}".sub(/^{{(.+)}}$/, '\1')
# => "foobar"
```

Comment: `"{{foo\nbar}}".sub(/{{(.+)}}/, '\1') #=>`"{{foo\nbar}}"`. You need multiline mode (`/m`). Also I suggest you use end-of-string rather than end-of-line anchors.

Answer (score 0):

Testing this out, it's clear that `chomp!` will return nil if the separator it's provided as an argument is not present at the end of the string.

So `"{{text}}".chomp!("}}")` returns a string, but `"{{text}}".chomp!("{{")` reurns nil.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238785/in-ruby-whats-the-easiest-way-to-chomp-at-the-start-of-a-string-instead-of-t) for an answer of how to `chomp` at the beginning of a string. But recognize that `chomp` only looks at the end of the string. So you can `call str.reverse.chomp!("{{").reverse` to remove the opening brackets.

You could also use a regex:

```
string = "{{text}}"
puts [/^\{\{(.+)\}\}$/, 1]
# => "text"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `tr`:

```
'{{foobar}}'.tr('{{', '').tr('}}', '')
```

You can also use `gsub` or `sub` but if the replacement is not needed as pattern, then `tr` should be faster.

If there are always curly braces, then you can just slice the string:

```
'{{foobar}}'[2...-2]
```

If you plan to make a method which returns the string without curly braces then DO NOT use bang versions. Modifying the input parameter of a method will be suprising!

```
def strip(string)
  string.tr!('{{', '').tr!('}}', '')
end
a = '{{foobar}}'
b = strip(a)
puts b #=> foobar
puts a #=> foobar
```

Comment: Read the question again, carefully. This does not answer it.

Comment: And what part is not answered?

Comment: `assume that the input string is always a tag which begins and ends with double curly braces.`

Comment: And my solution using ```tr``` (or gsub) will work for that. But I will update the sample code for you.

Comment: If  `str = '{{foo}}bar}}'` I assume `'foo}}bar'` is to be returned. In that case you can't use `tr`.

Comment: Good morning Cary. OP wrote: For the purposes of this question, you can assume that the input string is always a tag which begins and ends with double curly braces.

So I assumed it's only about striping the curly braces.